# Retriving info from a child class in the main program

Tags: c#, inheritance, console

So I'm trying to set up a basic timer function for healing after HP damage. I've got the timer working but it is calling from the parent Character class instead of the child class assigned to a single character and is therefore counting from zero instead of the number of HP left for that character. How do I get it to access the child instead of the parent?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace hpTimer_Test
{
    class Program
    {

        static Timer timer = new Timer(3000);        
        static int i = Knight.HP;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();            
            Console.Read();

        }
        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;

            //Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("=================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("                Health:  " + i.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("=================================================");

            if (i == 20)
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

---------- CHARACTER CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hpTimer_Test
{
    class Character
    {
        public static int HP = 0;
        public static int atkP = 0;
        public static bool Dash = false;
        public static double Target; //Equal to chosen enemy Loc
        public static bool isAttacking = false;
        public static int LocX = 1;
        public static int LocY = 1;

        public Character()
        {
        }

        public void HandleInput()
        {

        }

        //public override void Attack()
        //{
        //    if (isAttacking == true)
        //    {
        //        HP -= atkP;                
        //    }
        //}
    }    
}
```

----------KNIGHT CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hpTimer_Test
{
    class Knight : Character
    {
        public Knight()
        {
            HP = 10;
            atkP = 10;
            Dash = true;
            isAttacking = false;         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so have you even read / looked at the code that you posted..? `class Program` is the Parent class / class with the EntryPoint, so remove the code for the timer and place it in one of your child classes.. also where are you creating an instance of the other classes.. read up on the difference between `Instance classes and Static Classes` and methods as well..

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining it outside of its first use.

First don't use statics for the members of the Character class, otherwise everyone shares the value.
Second, don't declare int `i = Knight.H`P outside of main because you haven't created an object of type knight.

```
class Character
{
    public int HP;
    public int atkP = 0;
    public bool Dash = false;
    public double Target; //Equal to chosen enemy Loc
    public bool isAttacking = false;
    public int LocX = 1;
    public int LocY = 1;

    public Character()
    {
    }

    public virtual void HandleInput()
    {

    }

    //public override void Attack()
    //{
    //    if (isAttacking == true)
    //    {
    //        HP -= atkP;                
    //    }
    //}
}
```

Instead your program should be more like:

```
class Program 
{
    private static Character Player;

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Player = new Knight();
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();            
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Player.HP++;

        //Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("=================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                Health:  " + Player.HP);
        Console.WriteLine("");            Console.WriteLine("=================================================");

        if (i == 20)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

You definitely should rework your program as the MethodMan mentioned, you shouldn't use the timer just to control one characters health, instead you can set it up to handle anything that needs processing for your game.  If you have more than one character you can make them increase their health independently, but for now it is a start.